# Where did all these photos and videos come from?

Tags: insufficient-memory, photos, facebook, huawei

My phone's memory is so full that it won't let me take or download pictures anymore. Also cannot download almost any app due to low memory. When I look at memory usage, most of it is used for photos and videos. I plugged my phone into my computer and imported all photos and videos. I then would delete a bunch of them off my phone because they were now saved somewhere else. When I looked at what had been imported to my computer I saw hundreds of photos I have never taken or viewed before. Most of them were of people I know but have never taken pictures of. Also there were several video advertisements for brands like Colgate, McDonalds, and Gucci. I cannot find these photos or videos on my phone, or else I would delete them, they are almost certainly the reason for my phones low memory. All I can figure is that they must have come from Facebook. How do I find and delete these photos/videos, and also how do I prevent them from being saved to my phone?

Any help with this is much appreciated!

Comment: Without having the device on-hand myself, a few wild guesses only: it could be app caches (from advertisements); here some tools for [System Cleanup](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/tools_systemcleaner) might be helpful. As for the friends' photos: some stuff from social networks like Facebook, or shared stuff via Google+ photos could have brought those.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your facebook app is keeping a cache somewhere on your phone. Using an app like SD Maid, or any other phone cleaning application that searches for and deletes cache files such as this should solve this.